# Angular read onblur placeholder value from a variable instead of hardcoding it

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In Angular html, I have an input field as:

```
<input id="yy" name="yy" type="text" placeholder="{{ product }}"
         onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
         onblur="this.placeholder = 'xxx'">
```

With this when I take the mouse out of the input box, it shows placeholder value as xxx which is good

However, instead of hardcoding 'xxx', I want to read it from a variable defined in the component.ts

```
product = 'xxx'
```

In the template, I tried:

```
onblur="this.placeholder = {{product}}"
```

but that does not work. I tried a few other things but they dont work

Any idea how to set that placeholder value on blur with a variable instead of hardcoding a value there?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
  id="yy"
  name="yy"
  type="text"
  placeholder="{{ product }}"
  (focus)="this.placeholder = ''"
  (blur)="this.placeholder = product"
/>
```

should work fine. but this is manipulating some placeholder property on the component, not the placeholder of the input. you're not thinking about this in an angular fashion if you're trying to set the placeholder of the input.

you probably are trying for a set up like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-rwj1za?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It doesnt work. With this, it starts complaining that it cannot resolve placeholder

Comment: @user1892775 is placeholder defined in your code?

Comment: @rhavelka I updated my question above with the input element that has placeholder property.

Comment: which angular version are you using

Comment: Angular version 9

Comment: sorry made a mistake, see the update. but I think you're a little confused about what you may be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use template variable:

```
<input id="yy"
       name="yy"
       type="text"
       #inputRef
       [placeholder]="product"
       (focus)="inputRef.placeholder = ''"
       (blur)="inputRef.placeholder = product"/>
```

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks! Also, is there any issue in doing it this way? In the other answer it sounded like it was pointed out that there is a problem in this approach? I just needed to be able display the placholder text on mouse out and this looked like the way to do it, unless there is an issue that I am not aware of

Comment: I do not see any issue in this approach, you are getting HTML element reference via template variable within angular scope and modify it. This does not require ts file to be involved. When using `onfocus` and 'onblur' you are working within current element scope (not Angular) and `this` refers to HTML element, while in Angular scope it refers to current component

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can do this with just HTML/CSS and I find it cleaner, less JS in your component related to style/UI stuff.

This just takes away the placeholder (via font-size: 0) when you're focused on the input. Probably many different css properties you could use to achieve this but font-size does the trick for me.

```xml
<input 
  id="yy" 
  name="yy" 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="{{ product }}"
  class="input-test" />
```

```css
.input-test:focus::placeholder {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: this doesn't work in IE

Answer (score 0):

User,  you need change the variable "product", **not** this.placeholder. (Not exist nothing like this.placeholder). So you need two variables

You can, e.g. to have two variables "product" and "placeholder

```
<input id="yy" name="yy" type="text" 
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    (focus)="placeholder=''"
    (blur)="placeholder=product">
```

Or two variables "product" and "isOnfocus" and use the conditional operator

```
<input id="yy" name="yy" type="text" 
    [placeholder]="isOnFocus?'':product"
    (focus)="isOnFocus=true"
    (blur)="isOnFocus=false">
```

NOTE: in Angular you use (focus) and (blur)